# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup t_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup t_n\sqrt[n]{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $t_n\ge 0$. How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup t_n=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup t_n\sqrt[n]{n}$?

Here is my sketch: So $t_n\ge 0$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}\ge 1$ then $t_n\sqrt[n]{n}\ge t_n$ hence $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup t_n\sqrt[n]{n}\ge\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sup t_n.$$ How to prove the converse inequality?

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$.

Comment: I know that fact but I can't use it :(

Comment: Taking $t_n=1$ you can notice that the equality of lim sups in your question _implies_ $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$. I don't see any real way to answer your question without proving that limit as an intermediate step.

Comment: @RaheemNajib what Wojowu mentioned is a very basic fact. Why aren't you allowed to use it?

Comment: I can't understand you. Why you put $t_n=1$? It's meaningless since $t_n$ is arbitrarily sequence.

Comment: @AhmedHussein, I can't understand how to use it :( Here's my problem

Comment: @RaheemNajib well that's another thing. Hence the "Hint".

Comment: I can prove that $\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$. I have to prove above equality

Comment: @AhmedHussein, Can you show solution please? I would be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prove more general claim: If $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=1$ and $\lim\sup \limits_{n\to \infty}b_n=b$ then $\lim\sup \limits_{n\to \infty}a_nb_n=b.$

**Proof:** Let $X_1$ be the set of all subsequential limits of sequence $\{b_n\}$ and $X_2$ be the set of all subsequential limits of sequence $\{a_nb_n\}$. We prove that $X_1=X_2$.

Let $s\in X_1$ then $\exists \{n_k\}$ such that $b_{n_k}\to s$ as $k\to \infty$. Then $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}\to s$. Then $s\in X_2$ and $X_1\subseteq X_2$. Making converse reasoning we get that $X_2\subseteq X_1.$ Thus $X_1=X_2$ and $\sup X_1=\sup X_2$. Hence $$\lim\sup \limits_{n\to \infty}a_nb_n=\lim\sup \limits_{n\to \infty}b_n.$$